# Dynamically adding listboxes to view in ASP.net MVC 3

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, listbox

I am working on an ASP.net MVC 3 project.
Problem is:
I have a page. In that page, there will be a listbox which stores some categories.

 when user selects an item from that listbox, subcategories of selected category will be added to page. 

when user clicks the second listbox, third listbox will be added to page with it's own subcategories and scenario goes on like this.

i want to make this with ajax. i am stuck. 

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question. In the meantime you can provide us with some code showing what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking is: **"How can I make cascading dropdownlists in ASP.NET MVC?"**

If you formulate it like this, you don't even need to ask it here -- just Google that phrase and you will find links to lots of interesting stuff, including the following:

[Cascading DropDownList in ASP.Net MVC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx)

[Simple Implementation of MVC Cascading Ajax Drop Down](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/258172/Simple-Implementation-of-MVC-Cascading-Ajax-Drop-D)

Good luck!